# how to use apply (or sapply) with columns of matrix or dataframe as function args

Tags: r, apply, sapply

I know this is a bonehead newbie question, but I've been trying to figure it out for quite awhile and need some input.  Basically, I'm trying to learn how to use the apply family to omit for loops, specifically how to set up the call so that columns of a matrix serve as arguments to the function. I'll use a simple call to the rbinom function as an example.

Example: this for loop works fine. The data are a set of integers and a set of probabilities

```
success <- rep(-1, times=10)                             # initialize result var
num <- sample.int(20, 10)                                # get 10 random integers 
p <- runif(10)                                           # get 10 random probabilities
for (i in 1:10) {
  success[i]= rbinom(n=1, size=num[i],prob=p[i])          # number successes in 1 trial
}
```

But how to do the same thing with the apply family? I first put the data into 2 columns of a matrix, thinking that was the right start.  However, the following does NOT work, obviously due to my
poor understanding of how to set up a call to apply.

```
myData <- matrix(nrow=10, ncol=2)
myData[,1] <- num
myData[,2] <- p
success <- apply(myData, rbinom, n=1, size=myData[,1], prob=myData[,2])
```

Any tips are greatly appreciated!  I'm coming to R from Fortran, and trying to port over a lot of code that is loaded with DO loops, so I really need to get my head around this.

Answer (score 1):

`lapply`, `sapply`, `apply` only deal with one vector/list at a time. That is, `apply` will only call its function for one column at a time. What you need is `mapply` or `Map`.

```r
myData <- matrix(nrow=10, ncol=2)
myData[,1] <- num
myData[,2] <- p
mapply(rbinom, n = 1, myData[,1], myData[,2])
#  [1]  5  4 11  8  3  3 17  8  0 11
```

Just like `lapply` returns a list, so does `Map`; similarly, just like `sapply`, `mapply` will return a vector or array *if all return values are compatible*, otherwise it returns a `list` as well.

These calls are equivalent:

```t
sapply(1:3, function(z) z + 1)
mapply(function(z) z + 1, 1:3)
```

but `mapply` and `Map` allow arbitrary number of lists/vectors, so for instance

```r
func <- function(X,Y,Z) X^2+2*Y-Z
Map(func, 1:9, 11:19, 21:29)
## effectively the same as
list(
  func(1, 11, 21),
  func(2, 12, 22),
  func(3, 13, 33),
  ...,
  func(9, 19, 29)
)
```

The equivalent call of that with `sapply` for your data would be

```r
sapply(seq_len(nrow(myData)), function(ind) {
  rbinom(n = 1, size = myData[ind,1], prob = myData[ind,2])
})
```

though I personally feel that `mapply` is easier to read.

Comment: Wow -- thanks!  I've been banging my head against the wall all day, and you immediately put me on the right track.  I was confused because I read that apply could accept a matrix as input.  Lots to learn!

Comment: Glad it helps. For the record, `apply` *does* take a matrix as input ... but within that matrix, it operates on one "thing" at a time, whether that's one row or one column (or one pipe/plane, for arrays with more than 2 dimensions). It doesn't parallelize arguments, that's where `Map` and `mapply` shine.